# How to use ui-router to create dynamic links / views over json data?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I want this to work:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('view', {
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl:'../views/view.html',
    controller:'ViewCtrl',
    url:'/view/{index}'
  })


<tr ng-repeat="person in people">
   <td>
      <a href="/#/view/{{$index}}">{{person.fname + ' ' + person.lname}}</a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Module Config:

```
  .state('view', {
    templateUrl:'../views/view.html',
    controller:'ViewCtrl',
    url:'/view/{id:[0-9]{1,8}}'
  })
```

HTML:

```
<td>    
  <a ui-sref="view({id:{{person.id}}})">{{person.fname + ' ' + person.lname}}</a> 
</td>
```

..works now, however I can'#t fetch `$routeParams` on the view-page now.

Comment: $routeParams? Do you want $stateParams injected into your controller, or perhaps $state.params?

Answer (score 0):

Just write the expression directly inside the ui-sref, without the double brackets around person.id.

```
<a ui-sref="view({id: person.id})">{{person.fname + ' ' + person.lname}}</a>
```